Is the syntax of if statement wrong here?
  for num in {1..100};
    do
      if {[ ('$num%3' == 0) && ('$num%5' == 0) && ( '$num%15'!=0) ];}then
        echo "$num is valid\n"
      fi;
    done

I am trying to write a shell script that prints numbers between 1 to 100 which are divisible by 3 and 5 both but not divisible by 15 .
Getting error : syntax error near unexpected fi
Can anyone help pls?

Where did the curly braces come from?! And you need a new line or semicolon before then. And don’t put && within [ … ]; use Bash’s [[ … ]] or use multiple [ … ]. Oh, and spaces around operators and variables don’t expand within single quotes. Not to mention those % won’t actually do anything. It seems like a better resource for learning Bash would be in order.

Bash supports math mode: for ((num=1;num<=100;num++)); do if (( num%3 == 0 && num%5 == 0 && num%15 != 0 )); then echo "$num is valid\n"; fi; done. Anyway, it prints nothing, because the condition becomes never true.

divisible by 3 and 5 ==> divisible by 15. No integer can verify your condition.

The syntax of if is absolutely trivial.  Ignore all articles that say absurd garbage like "the syntax of if is if [ condition ]".  It is literally just adding the word if.  To run a command, you execute cmd.  To branch on the status of the command, you write if cmd; then ....; else ...; fi  Stop thinking that [ is in any way related to if.  Just purge [ from your brain and ignore any script that uses that command.  If you must use [, make things clear and spell it test.

You can use the curly braces but there's more syntax required to do so correctly. In particular you need a space after the {, and the } needs to be both a separate word (needs a space after it before the then!) and not parsed as an argument to any other command.

Did you try your script through shellcheck? This syntax is one of the correct possible: if (( ( num % 3 == 0 ) && ( num % 5 == 0 ) && ( num % 15 != 0 ) )) ;then ...

To get some useful hints add a suitable shebang (#!/bin/bash) to your script and then paste it at http://www.shellcheck.net/.

I think you mean "numbers divisible by 3 and numbers divisible by 5", not "numbers divisible by 3 and 5". Pay attention to when "and" in English means set union and when it means logical conjunction.

For some reason, there is a plethora of really bad information available about how to use an if statement in the shell.  It is absolutely trivial, and does not require much syntax.  It's just the words if, then, else (optional), and fi.  Any extraneous symbols you see are part of a command and have nothing to do with if.  Refactor your code to get the computation out of your way.
If you write a function called is_divisible_by_three that takes a single argument, you can use an if statement with it like:
if is_divisible_by_three "$num"; then echo "$num is divisible by 3"; fi

With a similar function for 5, you can write:
if is_divisible_by_three "$num" && is_divisible_by_five "$num"; then ...

You can chain commands into a list with symbols like && and || and ; and &, but this has nothing to do with the syntax of if.  To check the status of a list of commands, you simply precede it with the word if and follow up with then and (optionally) else and (not optional) fi.
You can even dynamically generate your divisibility functions and write something like:
#!/bin/bash

for i in 3 5; do
        eval "is_divisible_by_$i() {
                ! expr \$1 % $i > /dev/null
        }"
done

is_divisible_by_three() {
        ! expr $1 % 3 > /dev/null
}

is_divisible_by_five() {
        ! expr $1 % 5 > /dev/null
}

for i in {1..100}; do
        if is_divisible_by_5 $i && is_divisible_by_3 $i; then
                echo $i is divisible by 3 and 5
        fi
done

Whether you want to use expr or (( or something else to actually do the computation is irrelevant for this question, but I will at least point out that expr is pretty old-fashioned and you probably shouldn't use it...but it's not relevant to the question.  Don't be confused by if; there is simply nothing confusing about it.  Branch on a command by preceding it with the keyword if and following it with then.  For example:
if cmd
then
echo cmd succeeded
else
echo cmd failed
fi

Anything after an if that looks "complicated" is just a command.  It has nothing to do with the syntax of if.  For some reason, in the 70s someone thought it would be cute to name the test command [ and require that its final argument be ], and since then millions of people have made the mistake of believing that [ is somehow related to the syntax of the if keyword.  It is not.  Ignore any article that ties the two together, and realize that the syntax of if is nearly trivial.  if ...; then ...; else ...; fi Anything in the ellipses that looks "complicated" has nothing to do with the syntax of if.

You mention chaining commands with && and ||, but if one does, one needs to be aware that they do not have the expected precedence of Boolean and and or operators; a || b && c, for example, is equivalent to { a || b; } && c, not a || { b && c; }.

I don't see a point, why you want to use statement grouping ({....}) here.
Since you are using bash, I would simply write the condition as
if (( num%3 == 0 && num%5 == 0 && num%15 != 0 ))
then
  ...
fi

but this asks for for numbers, which are divisible by 3 and 5, but not divisible by 15, and since such numbers obviously don't exist, you can simply comment out your whole loop and not execute anything.

Yeah, the original question doesn't make a lot of sense.  15 is the lowest number that 3 and 5 both go into.  All other common divisors are multiples of 15.

you can use it like this :
#! /usr/bin/bash

for num in {1..100}; do
  if [ $(($num % 3)) -eq 0 ] && [ $(($num % 5)) -eq 0 ] && [ $(($num % 15)) -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "$num is valid"
  fi
done

NOTE: While you are looking for numbers that are divisible by both 3 and 5 at the same time, you are also looking for numbers that are not divisible by 15, but all numbers that are divisible by both 3 and 5 must be divisible by 15. The least common multiple of 3 and 5 is 15. That's why you can't see anything in the output

Do you mean 3 or 5? Or 3 and 5?


Note that since bash specifically is being used, you can write a clearer (but not POSIX-compliant) version if (( num % 3 == 0 && num % 5 == 0 && num % 15 != 0 )); then ...

Indeed, the code is already not POSIX compliant, since {1..100} is a bashism.
